# Symfony2 complex routing structure

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony-2.1

How can I implement the following routing structure:

```
pattern: /{category}
```

yet also have many other fixed patterns such as

```
pattern: /register
pattern: /login
pattern: /help
```

I know one way is to require regex for the category variable so that category is not equal to any of the fixed patterns. However, if I were to have 50+ different fixed patterns for the system, it would become a bit messy. Is there a clean and effective way to implement this routing structure?

I DO NOT want to compromise doing something like:

```
pattern: /something/{category}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply place

```
pattern: /{category}
```

in the end of the routing.yml

Comment: But beware if you add anything to URL that is provided by user (even an administrator), as you can create a page that's impossible to display.